# Newrelic - Filter by Request Parameter

Tags: ruby, newrelic

New Relic show me for example action (Show) and Traffic to the action, I want to see for this action filtered by different paramter, Ex: `Show id=15, id=20, id=35` this is simple example my case is I have multiple clients and each client access my website service with different id and I want to track how frequent each one access my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::NewRelic::Agent.add_custom_parameters(:key => value)` to grab the parameters (more info [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/newrelic_rpm/NewRelic/Agent%3aadd_custom_parameters)).

To be able to filter by different parameters, you should take a look at New Relic Insights (more info [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/newrelic-insights)).